# reverse of toJson() - deserialise JSON to models

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I load models with relations (like a book, authors, publisher, keywords) and send it out to the web interface in JSON. Users will edit it there, and then the interface will send it back as JSON. The question is how do I create a model from the JSON (the opposite of toJson() call) and then save it to the database. It would also be helpful if I could compare the original data - reloaded from the db again - with the data I receive from the web layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the JSON once it's received by the server:

```
$decoded = json_decode( Input::get('json') );
```

If you want to compare the models one option is grabbing the ID of the model from your decoded JSON (make sure you double check the user has access to it in case they try fudging the data on you), loop over your key/values for your decoded data and match them against each other.

```
$model = YourModel::find( $decoded->id ); // dont forget to ensure they have access to this model

// Set up an empty array to store anything that's changed
$changes = array();

// Loop over your decoded values
foreach( $decoded as $key => $value ) {

    // If the value in your model doesn't match the decoded value, add to the changes array
    if( $model->{$key} != $value ) {
        $changes[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but only with a flat model I guess. My model has relations, and as I understand if I make changes server side after loading it, I can do a ->save() on it. Now this is what I want to do with the model (and it's relations) received over the wire. So the key question is here, how do I create a model (with relations) from JSON.

Comment: You can pass through your model with relationships by doing YourModel::find( $model_id) )->with('relationship')->toJson(). If you want to check for changes on the parent and child models at any point just check the format of your decoded JSON object and loop over its relationships with similar key/value checks as in the answer.

Comment: In that case I'd probably create a check method with the logic above that returns an array of changed values given two objects or arrays and reuse it for the properties on your parent model and any other related models.

Answer (score -1):

you can convert it to a `collection` by using `collect(json_decode($json))`.

[collection Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#creating-collections)

Comment: I need to convert it to a model, with relations, that I can save. Would a collection help with that?